# How can I know what are the changes in Robot Framework IDE (RIDE) development?

Tags: robotframework-ide

It is difficult to know what will be changed, new or fixed in RIDE.

How can we obtain that information?

Answer (score 1):

The [RIDE project](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/) now have a CHANGELOG that you can consult [here](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/CHANGELOG.adoc).

You can see at the top of the document:

> **Changelog**

> All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.
>
> The format is based on Keep a Changelog and this project adheres to
> Semantic Versioning.

You may also follow developments at https://forum.robotframework.org/, specifically  on the [RIDE topic](https://forum.robotframework.org/c/tools/ride/21).